# How can I add a image click function to gallery.php temp code?

Tags: php, image, joomla, hyperlink

Ok so here is the link to the template code for gallery.

https://github.com/JoomShaper/Helix-Joomla/blob/master/helixPlugin/shortcodes/gallery.php

However when I insert images on my database (not in Php), the image shows up but I am unable to click that image and be directed to the images page, which I have hyperlinked on my database (Joomla).  I will have multiple images where I will need to add this click function to.

I have been trying to figure this out forever. I am new to Php and coding, so forgive my ignorant use of word choices from the above paragraphs.

(I've noticed in the past when speaking to coders it is frustrating for them to code the jargon from a someone who doesn't know the language ha!) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is not an answer probably, but I cannot comment yet. I have been looking at your code for a little while, and I noticed some things I wanted to ask you about. First:

```
 <?php foreach ($galleryArray as $key=>$item) { ?>        
    <li style="width:<?php echo round(100/$columns); ?>%" class="<?php echo str_replace(',', ' ', $item['tag']) ?>">
        <a class="img-polaroid" data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo ($modal=='yes')? '#modal-' . $key . '':'#' ?>">
          <?php
            echo '<img alt=" " src="' . $item['src'] . '" />';
           ?>
            <?php if($item['content'] !='') { ?>
             <div>
                <div>
                  <?php echo do_shortcode($item['content']); ?>
                </div>
             </div>
           <?php } ?>
         </a>
       </li>
```

You begin your a and li inside the foreach loop, but you finish them outside of it. Considering that the a is your link, and your link is not working, I thought this could be part of your issue.

Also, I noticed that when you link to the modal, you use the same variables from the loop, but the variables were defined inside the loop and would not carry over on clicking the link that was generated. It seems to me that you would need to define a property value with the variable you need from each one, so that you can use JS to do something along the lines of "onClick" grab "this.property.value" so that you could have that information in the modal.

I only thought this was of note because the modal you are opening with the link is named by one of these variables. Unless you are creating a separate modal for each one inside the foreach loop, the name you are linking to does not exist. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: I understand! OK how would you go about defining the property vaue with variable?

Comment: For instance, in the foreach loop, say you want to add a name that you could grab. You could do something like:

(leaving out alot of your code to make it easier)
foreach ($galleryArray as $key=>$item) {
    <li>
      <a name="<?php echo $key ?>"></a>
    </li>

Now, you will have the name property on each link set as the key it refers to.

Comment: Ok I replaced "name" for href ---- href="<?php echo $key?>"   and now this time when I clicked my image it went to the practicing server....joomla.example.com\0  what does the 0 refer to? And instead of making it go to \0, what variables would I need to put in the href to make the path to the image hyperlink?  thanks for your help.

Comment: And I'm seeing your comment regarding onClick, I believe that is what I need.

Comment: What is an example of a $key that you are pulling in the loop? I ask because if you set it as href, it would have to be exactly where you are going. If you are opening "#modal-[whatever your key is]#", then that is what needs to be in $key if it is your href. However, what I was saying is that on clicking the anchor, javascript could get the value of "name", concatenate it to make #modal-[whatever your key is]#, then create the modal based on that.

Comment: http://joomla.diversal.org/features  this is my test server.  I want to where you click the image and are directed to the site that I have hyperlinked to the image in Joomla.

Comment: This is the current loop where the image is in <?php foreach ($galleryArray as $key=>$item) { ?>               
           <li style="width:<?php echo round(100/$columns); ?>%" class=""> 
                                   
                                <a class="submit active" href="<?php echo $key?>"</a> <?php echo '<img alt=" "  src="' . $item['src'] . '" class="btn link">'?> <?php if($item['content'] !='') { ?><?php echo do_shortcode($item['content']); ?></div></div><?php } ?> </a></li>